# How to check if material-components-web or MDC-Web is supported by a browser

Tags: material-design, material-components, material-components-web

I implemented MDC-Web in a webpage and it works with Chrome/Firefox on smartphones. However, [select menu](https://material-components-web.appspot.com/select.html) component is not working for Samsung browser on mobile devices.

I'm looking for a way to check if a MDC component is supported by a browser, in my JavaScript code, rather than checking out manually on every single browser available.

Does anybody know how I can do that? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To temporarily solve your select menu issue try Material Components Web 0.29.0 (or less), using the css only implementation, that relies on native element:

```
  <div class="mdc-select">
     <select class="mdc-select__surface" id="demo-select">
        <option value="1">First</option>
        <option value="2" selected>Second</option>
        <option value="3">Third</option>
     </select>
     <div class="mdc-select__bottom-line"></div>
  </div>
```

After 0.29.0 they removed this implementation, but they are [reverting back](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/issues/2399).

Sadly I don't know if there is a resource to check browser compatibility against MDC Web.